# How to listen to events sent from objects in a minimised script

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, eventemitter

On a website, there is a minimised script, which runs when the document loads, which emits events. Is it possible to to listen for these events?

How would I get the target needed to be listened to, if the target is an object constructed by a class.

Thankyou.

(Sorry if this is unclear, I don't have the vocabulary describe it properly.)

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect Event Listeners using DevTools. In Chrome, that's in `Elements > Event Listeners`:

[image]

You can also find the original event listener in the minimized code and add a breakpoint there in the Sources tab. There's a `Pretty print` option there that will help you navigate that minimized code:

[image]